# Contribution emails not being sent - Direct Deposit/Pay Later

Tags: wordpress, civicontribute, email, 4.7, receipts

For online contributions, the only email that gets sent is when the contributor pays immediately (receipt). Thank you emails are not automatically sent and I cannot work out whether this is functioning as designed. When the direct deposit option is selected, no email is automatically sent out.

In addition there is a setting on the profile we use for contributions to notify when the form is submitted. This has not been working either.

After some research, I enabled the CiviContribute setting to automatically email invoices (enable tax and invoicing section) which made the email notification of profile submissions work for some reason, but not the invoice/receipts for pay later.

Any suggestions on how I can troubleshoot?  CiviCRM v4.7.8 but this has been an issue since 4.7

Edit/Update: 
If I disable automatic email of invoices, no emails are sent unless pay now (including profile submission email). If I enable automatic email invoice I get a pdf invoice every time as well as a profile submission email. This is fine as a workaround but if anyone knows a way to get it to email without a pdf attachment, that would be better. I received intermittent emails without pdfs (one with an amount, one without amount) while I was testing a couple of hours ago, then the pdfs started arriving consistently, so I customised those as a way forward.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this [bug](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-18118) but it should have been fixed in 4.7.4

Comment: Almost the same, except the pay later instructions do appear on the contribution page when that option is selected. As another test I disabled the automatic emailing of invoices and the notification of profile submission has stopped working again. I cannot figure out how they are related.

Comment: Well I don't know what is going on but it seems to be working after all that enabling and disabling of various options. I can't say which thing did the trick because I have reverted to the original settings when the problem as when the issue was reported. I guess something has been overwritten. Or.. could it be some kind of caching issue?

Comment: Now all I need is for the receipt to show an amount...